# How to import variable file dynamically in robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I am working in robot framework. I have two variables files in it. I want to pass these variables files dynamically. In certain condition I want to send a.py and in others b.py. But this information I want to pass dynamically.
Can you please help me with this

Comment: When you say "pass these variable files dynamically", what do you mean? Pass them from where? Pass them to where? Do you mean that you want to pass them into a keyword? Or, are you saying you want to pass them from the command line to a test suite?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [Import library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Import%20Library) keyword to manually import an external file.

Then use the [Run Keyword If](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20If) keyword to check which library to import. For example:

```
Run Keyword If   '${VAR}' == 'a'   Import Library   a.py
Run Keyword If   '${VAR}' == 'b'   Import Library   b.py
```

You can pass the `VAR` as a parameter to your test:

```
pybot --variable VAR:a TestSuite
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import files based on the variable you are passing during execution

```
*** Settings ***
Variables    config_${TEST_ENVIRONMENT}.yaml

*** Test Cases ***

*** Keywords ***
```

Robot command to execute:

```
$ robot --variable TEST_ENVIRONMENT:local file_name.robot
```

Comment: Did this ever work?

Comment: Yes, It is working for me and should work for you as well.

Comment: yes it ended up working, I was facing a non-related issue apparently.